# How to use a variable from 1 function in another function - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web3js

I have here 2 functions that depend on each other

```
async function block() {
  let getBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  console.log(getBlock['number']);
  let lblock = getBlock['number'] - 8;
  console.log(lblock);
}
block();

pcsfactoryC.events.PairCreated({
  fromBlock: lblock
})
```

With the async function I get the latest block and than do some calculations and I get the variable lblock which I use than in below functions as input for
`{fromBlock: lblock}`

So how can I use the varibable "lblock" in the other function?

Comment: return it from the first function with `return lblock;`

Comment: you have to `await` any result from `block()` otherwise all you'll get is a `Promise`, not the actual return value.

Comment: also - why is `block` even `async` if it's not waiting for a result from `web3.eth.getBlock()` ?

Comment: isnt working, it says lblock isnt defined

Answer (score 1):

Return it from the function.

Since `block()` is `async`, it returns a promise. You either have to use `await` to wait for it (you can only do this if the other function is also `async`, or use `.then()` to execute a function when the promise is resolved.

```
async function block() {
  let getBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  console.log(getBlock['number']);
  let lblock = getBlock['number'] - 8;
  console.log(lblock);
  return lblock;
}
block().then(lblock => pcsfactoryC.events.PairCreated({
  fromBlock: lblock
}));
```

Comment: this is insufficient if `getBlock()` is also async.

Comment: fwiw, it's generally bad form to mix explicit promise chaining and `async` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Eventually you reach the end of the chain of `async` functions, so you can't use `await` there and must switch back to `.then()`

Comment: get block is async/await function i edited it and i dont need the last 8blocks everytime i get the newPair, I only want when someone visits the site that he sees the latest pairs from 8 blocks ago

Comment: You do that by controlling when you call the second function.

Answer (score -2):

let a function abc() { a=10 }

function xyz() { alert(a) }

abc() xyz()

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.